# How to use User's current IP address as the proxy in PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Is it possible to use user's current IP address as the proxy address with PHP cURL? Currently, I am trying following code but giving request time out error. I test it with hma proxy it is working fine but when I'm trying to uses user's IP address it is giving request time error in the server's log.

```
function get_page($url){

$proxy=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].":80";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // return headers 0 no 1 yes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return page 1:yes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); // http request timeout 20 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follow redirects, need this if the url changes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2); //if http server gives redirection responce
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // cookies storage / here the changes have been made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // false for https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // the page encoding

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute the http request
curl_close($ch); // close the connection
return $data;
}
```

There are a lots of live examples which is doing same. For example these two tools from Google

1. google.com/gwt/x
2. developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are assuming a http proxy exists running on port 80 of the users machine.

Comment: That's the problem, m not able to decide. I know it is possible but how I dont know that.

Comment: It would be good to get some context regarding what you are trying to achieve here so we can possibly offer alternative options.

Comment: Are you certain that the remote address has got a proxy server running on port 80? Port 80 is the default port for a web server, not a proxy

Comment: Well, I am trying to fetch data from a particular website which limits the request so using (users IP as) proxy I want to fetch the data without any problem.

Comment: You can't just use someone as a proxy, there has to be a proxy server running at the address that you specify in CURLOPT_PROXY

Comment: There is pages peed insight tool from Google which is doing the same. It uses user's IP and even logs in the server. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82995/discussion-between-disk01-and-pix06).

Comment: @Disk01 It looks like that Google page runs a Javascript function when you submit the form, it's not doing the work on the server. Although I'm not sure how it gets around the AJAX same-domain requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. While you COULD make your server issue a SYN packet using the user's IP as the "source", any reply packets from the target machine will go to the USER's machine, not your server.

It is NOT possibl to spoof a complete TCP connection unless you control the network infrastructure upstream of the target/victim.